# Call admin function from another admin in django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a `products/admin.py` as follows

```
# django imports
from django.contrib import admin

# model imports
from products.models import Product
from inventory.models import Inventory


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = # some fields in a tuple
    readonly_fields = # some more fields in a tuple

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if 'is_active' in form.data:
            if form.data['is_active'] == 'on':
                # create an Inventory if product doesn't exists. 
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.updated_by = request.user
        if change:
            obj.updated_by = request.user
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

I have a `inventory/admin.py` as follows

```
# django imports
from django.contrib import admin

# models imports
from inventory.model import Inventory, DispatchedInventory


class InventoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.updated_by = request.user
        if change:
            obj.updated_by = request.user
        obj.save()
    readonly_fields = ['created_by', 'updated_by']
```

Now I want to call `InventoryAdmin.save_model()` inside `ProductAdmin.save_model()` when `if form.data['is_active'] == 'on':` is true. 
My motivation behind it is that to create an inventory for the product when product is made active.
I know how to create by taking an instance of Inventory model itself like as follows( which will be last resort):

```
inventory_instance = Inventory.objects.get_or_create(product=product)
```

But calling the admin functions does all the job for me so I want to figure out a way to achieve it.

What I've tried so far is to pass `InventoryAdmin` as params:

```
class ProductAdmin(InventoryAdmin):
    list_display = # some fields in a tuple
    readonly_fields = # some more fields in a tuple
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if 'is_active' in form.data:
            if form.data['is_active'] == 'on':
                # couldn't figure out what to write here.
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not, quite sure, if you are on the right track here, but if you want to call a method in an admin instance, you need to do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite

adm = InventoryAdmin(Inventory, AdminSite())
inv = Inventory.objects.get_or_create(product=product)
adm.save_model(request, inv, form, change)
```

Not really worth the effort is it? This is three lines of code, the InventoryAdmin only has 6

But looking closely, I think I can spot a bug in InventoryAdmin,

```
obj.updated_by = request.user
if change:
    obj.updated_by = request.user
```

You are updating the updated_by regardless of whether or not a change has happened, so that's another line shaved off!

Really, all you need to do in your ProductAdmin is

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if 'is_active' in form.data:
        if form.data['is_active'] == 'on':
            inv = Inventory.objects.get_or_create(product=obj,
                       created_by=request.user, updated_by=request_user)
```

Comment: Well.. I had set updated_by as mandatory field but yes it was a bug! So my question is how to invoke the inventory admin functions.

Comment: and that information is what's provided in the first code fragment in my answer

Comment: Thanks for your inputs here.

Comment: glad to have helped